# Uitableview when scrolling past a certain point

Tags: ios, uitableview, scroll

i have looked through basically every single stack overflow question on this, but i cant find an answer. None of the answers seem to work.

I am writing an application that has a tableview in it, with a uitableview as a subview.
The uitableview is datasource and delegate connected to a class called xvalues, which is a subclass of uitableviewcontroller. i also have a class, where i load a custom uitableviewcell. This all doesn't cause any errors.

Here is my code for the uitableview, in xvalues:

```
    - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
    {
        // Return the number of sections.
        return 1;
    }

    - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
    {
        // Return the number of rows in the section.
        return 1;
    }

    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        tableviewcell *cell = [[tableviewcell alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectZero];

        return cell;
   }
    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        // Navigation logic may go here. Create and push another view controller.
        /*
         <#DetailViewController#> *detailViewController = [[<#DetailViewController#> alloc] initWithNibName:@"<#Nib name#>" bundle:nil];
         // ...
         // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
         [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
         [detailViewController release];
         */
    }
```

I removed some commented out methods such as can edit row at index path and commit editing style.

In cellforrowatindexpath, tableviewcell is my custom cell class.

From this, when i run my code, it loads up my uitableview, with 1 cell, with my custom cell.
However, now, if i click and drag, it works for dragging about an inch, and then suddenly crashes with the error:

```
2012-07-16 12:14:16.957 spreadsheet[68717:f803] -[__NSCFString tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6894400
2012-07-16 12:14:16.960 spreadsheet[68717:f803] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6894400'
*** First throw call stack: blah blah blah
```

It also happens when i click on the row, but i think that is because of my did select row at index path method.

If anyone could help me it would be amazingly helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Your table view controller is getting deallocated. Make sure you’re retaining your `xvalues` instance (or assigning it to a `strong` property on something, like your app delegate) wherever you’re creating it.

Comment: But even if i create a new uitableview application, it still crashes.
I dont think its my code. i think it is part of the default uitableview code... Any ideas?